# UnicodeEncodeError in a Debian terminal

Tags: python, unicode, terminal, debian

guys! I'm in a Debian 7 terminal trying to run a python script that sends a message via telegram-cli. The following line gives me an error:

```
check_call(["/usr/local/tg/bin/telegram-cli", "-W", "-k", "/usr/local/tg/tg-server.pub", "-e", msg])
```

At the end of this line, "msg" is a variable...

The error is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LogServicos.py", line 60, in <module>
    msg_telegram()
  File "LogServicos.py", line 17, in msg_telegram
    check_call(["/usr/local/tg/bin/telegram-cli", "-W", "-k", "/usr/local/tg/tg-server.pub", "-e", msg])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 579, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 560, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1483, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe7' in position 25: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The script is fully fuctional on my debian 15.10 using python 3.5.1, the same as in Debian.

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The command line arguments passed to `telegram-cli` contain non-ascii characters, in this case `msg` contains the character `ç` (`\xe7`). On *nix, file names and command line arguments are just bytes in the end, so unicode strings need to be converted to bytes to be used as such.

python [uses `sys.getfilesystemencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#file-names-command-line-arguments-and-environment-variables) for such conversions, which usually depends on the `LANG` and `LC_*` environment variables.

In your case on the computer where this program fails, the default locale only supports ascii (possibly the `C` locale), you can use the `locale` command to see which one is exactly used.

To fix this error, you can either:

- encode `msg` when passing it to the command line, but that will only work correctly if `telepathy-client` doesn't also rely on the current locale to interpret it, otherwise you may end up with garbage characters
- make sure the correct locale is set in the environment where you're running your script. You can use `locale -a` to check which locales are supported on your system, if no suitable locale shows up in the list, you may need to install a suitable new locale (like described [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Locale#Manually) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76013/how-do-i-add-locale-to-ubuntu-server))